# How to make a button truly circular in Semantic UI

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

If I add the `circular` class to a button with words in it, the button doesn't really become a circle, just a rectangle with rounded edges:

[image]

How do I make the button become a circle? I want its diameter to be the same as that of the one above, but have more fill in the top and bottom so that it looks like a circle.

My HTML currently looks like this:

```
<div id="my-button" class="ui circular animated button" tabindex="0">
    <div class="visible content">A button</div>
    <div class="hidden content">
        <i class="right arrow icon"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: Alternatively, what would be an easy way to make a circular button with text in it? I'm not hellbent on using Semantic UI.

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the button a rounded circle you must have it's height exactly the same as it's width. Since the button element is inline-block, it's width is based on it's content, so you need a bit of javascript to set the width as the `line-height` of that element.

I added a new class to the circulate and also set the line-height of the `content` (to make sure the arrow is also centered).

Check this example:

```js
$('.full-circle').each(function() {
  $(this).css('lineHeight', $(this).width() + 'px');
});
```

```css
.full-circle.ui.animated.button .hidden.content {
  line-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.4/semantic.css" />
<div id="my-button" class="ui circular animated button full-circle" tabindex="0">
    <div class="visible content">A button</div>
    <div class="hidden content">
        <i class="right arrow icon"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```